# Translate Excel Spreadsheets with SOLVER in C#

Tags: c#, excel, solver

After several searches and mistakes on my part, I finally managed to get out of it and get a result from the MSF solver.

However, it's not perfect, because I still have a difference against me in my C# code.

In the Excel workbook I have 6 solvers, relatively identical.
Only one solver per tab, but I have a lot of calculations.

In order to best stick to the Excel workbook, I created one method per cell containing a formula.
My code works, in the sense that if I give it the same data as Excel I have the same results, but with the solver I have a little difference.

Here's what I did, and I'd like you to tell me if there's anything I can improve by trying to keep my methods (representing my Excel Cells)

Each representation of the cells is created twice.
I need to have the value of my cell to do other calculations and it seems that I can't put methods returning a double, in the solver.

Classic method:

```
private double Cell_I5()
{
    double res = 0;
    res = (Math.Exp(-Var.Calc.Var4 * Var.Calc.De * M23) - 1) / (-Var.Calc.Var4 * Var.Calc.De * M23);
    return res;
}
```

Method for the solver:

```
private Term Solv_I5()
{
     Term res = 0;
     res = (Model.Exp(-Var.Calc.Var4 * Var.Calc.De * Solver_M23) - 1) / (-Var.Calc.Var4 * Var.Calc.De * Solver_M23);
     return res;
}
```

'M23' is a double
'Solver_M23' is a Decision
'Var4' is a double as well as 'De'.
So I use the return value with "Term" and I change all the Math functions to 'Model', except Math.Pi which is a constant.

You can imagine that there are close to 60 to 70 methods involved like that.

My method for the solver:

```
public void StartSolver()
{
    var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
    solver.ClearModel();
    var model = solver.CreateModel();
    //Instanciation des variables du Solver en format Real(double) Non Negative
    Solver_M22 = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "M22");
    Solver_M23 = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "M23");
    Solver_M24 = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "M24");
    Solver_M25 = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "M25");
    Solver_M26 = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "M26");

    model.AddDecision(Solver_M22);
    model.AddDecision(Solver_M23);
    model.AddDecision(Solver_M24);
    model.AddDecision(Solver_M25);
    model.AddDecision(Solver_M26);

    model.AddConstraint("M22a", Solver_M22 <= 4);
    model.AddConstraint("M22b", Solver_M22 >= 0);
    model.AddConstraint("M23a", Solver_M23 <= 2);
    model.AddConstraint("M23b", Solver_M23 >= 0.001);
    model.AddConstraint("M24a", Solver_M24 <= 2);
    model.AddConstraint("M24b", Solver_M24 >= 0);
    model.AddConstraint("M25a", Solver_M25 <= 2);
    model.AddConstraint("M25b", Solver_M25 >= 0);
    model.AddConstraint("M26a", Solver_M26 <= 2);
    model.AddConstraint("M26b", Solver_M26 >= 0.001);
    
    //Test with classical calculation methods
    double test = Cell_H33() + Cell_H23();

    //Adding Solver Methods
    model.AddGoal("SommeDesCarresDesEquartsGlobal", GoalKind.Minimize, Solv_H33() + Solv_H23());
    
    // Solve our problem
    var solution = solver.Solve();
    
    // Get our decisions
    M22 = Solver_M22.ToDouble();
    M23 = Solver_M23.ToDouble();
    M24 = Solver_M24.ToDouble();
    M25 = Solver_M25.ToDouble();
    M26 = Solver_M26.ToDouble();
    string s = solution.Quality.ToString();

    //For test
    double testSortie = Cell_H33() + Cell_H23();
    }
```

Questions:

1)
At no time do I indicate whether it is a linear calculation or not. How to indicate if necessary?
In Excel it is declared nonlinear
I saw that the solver was looking for the best method on its own.

2)
Is there something I'm not doing right, because I don't have the same value (with Excel)? I checked several times all the methods by one, with the amount that I missed, maybe, something, I will recheck tomorrow.

3)
Apart from doing the calculation with the classic methods, I have not found a way to find my result. From the 'solution' object
How to extract it from the result if possible?

4)
Here is the result of the 5 variables I find MSF C#:
0.06014756519010750
0.07283670953453890
0.07479568348101340
0.02864805010533950
0.00100000002842722

And what I find the Excel solver:
0.0000
0.0010
0.0141
0.0000
0.0010
Is there a way to restrict the number of decimal places directly in the calculations?
Because when I reduce manually (after calculation) that changes my result quite a bit?

Thank you.

[EDIT] Forgot to post this message it was still pending.
This morning I ran the C# solver calculation again and the result is really different with a huge difference in the result.

I remind you that I want to minimize the result.
Excel = 3.92
C#=8122.34

Result not acceptable at all.

[EDIT 2]
I may have a clue:

When I doing a simple calculation, such as:

```
private Term Solv_I5()
{
     Term res = 0;
     res = Model.Exp(-Var.Calc.Var4 * Var.Calc.Den * Solver_M25);
     return res;
}
```

the result is:

```
{Exp(Times(-4176002161226263/70368744177664, M25))}
```

Why "Times"
All formulas with multiplication contain Times.
For divisions there is 'Quotient', additions 'Plus', but multiplications 'Times !!!

Question 4)
Am I doing the multiplications wrong in a 'Term'.?
Do you have an idea?

[EDIT 3]
I just saw that "times" was not a stupid term, another misunderstanding on my part of the English language, sorry.

So that doesn't solve my problem.

Can you help me please.

Comment: Question 2 is in French, you might want to translate it.

Comment: Reducing decimals does not mean removing significant numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate excel spreadsheets"? Rewrite the algorithm in C#? Or use C# to call the Solver multiple times? If the title is not clear...

Comment: Hello,
-Sorry for my broken English, and the sentence I left in French (corrected)

-For decimals, this is not my main problem, I grant you that. We can put that aside for now.

-At the moment the user is using a large excel workbook, but my goal is to delete this excel file.
So I have to create an application in C# using Microsoft solver foundation, to solve identically the solvers present in Excel as well as all the calculations.
I'm not stuck with MSF, another solver would do if it worked fine.